# How can I synchronize one online sql database with another offline database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, synchronization, mirroring

I need to sync a large local SQL database to a server database and vice versa. The two databases structure are exactly the same. We need to get latest data from online server once a day in morning. The local DB is constantly updated and every hour or so the server DB need to be updated with the local data.

I want to do it with a .Net winforms application.

I thought that I can achieve this in two parts as :

1. Create a backup of online database, then download it and restore the local database   with that backup file (as our online database is updated one).
2. then say after an hour I will check for new entries in local database and update/Insert new entries in online database.

But I have some issues in this approach:

1. When we download large database backup file, several times it's got corrupted.
2. My database has primary keys and foreign key references for Parent/child relationship tables. So if I generate a new row in online database then it will generate new Id's in online database. So how can I maintain references?

I never worked with this kind of scenario, I don't know the different ways for achieving this so please explain yourself as good as possible.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you would be better off using sql server replication rather than writing this yourself

[links to msdn information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can give the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default) a try.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an article upon on-line off-line database synchronization. here you can find how to synchronize multiple databases (same schema).there should be one master database and others will be updated according to it. you can try this : http://blog.ankitverma.com/2010/03/onlineoffline-database-synchronization/

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following software for database synchronization:

1. Sql Compare: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/
2. Sql Delta: http://www.sqldelta.com